# Automatically enable Public Link on Attachment Upload So the user doesn't have to do it manually

Tags: apex, trigger

We want all case attachments to immediately generate a public URL when a user uploads a file.

I am struggling to find fields to auto-create this via apex in the ContentVersion object. I know that the ContentDistribution object binds the attachment with the document, I am just struggling to see how we can auto-create this.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can add an after insert trigger on ContentVersion SObject which creates corresponding ContentDistribution & insert it to DB.
The idea would be similar to :
Trigger:

```
trigger ContentVersionTrigger on ContentVersion (after insert) {
    if(Trigger.IsInsert && Trigger.IsAfter){
        ContentVersionTriggerHandler.doAfterInsert(Trigger.New);
    }
}
```

Handler:

```
public static void doAfterInsert(List<ContentVersion> cvList) {
    if(!cvList.IsEmpty()){
        List<ContentDistribution> cdListToInsert = new List<ContentDistribution>();
        for(ContentVersion cv : cvList){
            cdListToInsert.add(new ContentDistribution(
                ContentVersionId = cv.Id,
                Name = cv.Title
            ));
        }
        if(!cdListToInsert.IsEmpty())INSERT cdListToInsert;
        System.debug(cdListToInsert); //your ContentDistribution which will have public & download URL for the file.
    }
}
```

Thats all you need, you should be able to view the file using DistributionPublicUrl & ContentDownloadUrl field on ContentDistribution.

Comment: Thank you- this is working for me. However, be aware the link will not show in the file details in the UI. You can only access the link by doing a SOQL query.